# Cron job of multiple php files with a php script

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

For me cronjob is a very new feature, so I would need some help from you guys.

I need to create a cronjob that will run at every 8 hours some php scripts.

```
    vend_1.php
    vend_2.php
    vend_3.php
    vend_4.php
    vend_5.php
    vend_6.php
    vend_7.php
    vend_8.php
    vend_9.php
```

Location of php scrips is within my theme on wordpress. 
    So the path is :`"/wp-content/themes/mythemename/vend_1.php`"

I know that i need to have permissions so i set `0777` for all the files.
I already found how to run at every 8 hours:" `0 */8 * * *` ".
I created the file cron.php within my theme path: `/wp-content/themes/mythemename/cron.php`

**I don't know what i need to put in my cron.php**. So I will be very happy is someone could help me.

Comment: See basic info about `crontab` in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info. Note you need to use `crontab -e` to edit the file.

Comment: Rather make a cron.sh and put <pathtophp> <filename> for each script. EG: /usr/bin/php /wp-content/themes/mythemename/vend_1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file `phpcron.sh` with `chmod 777` .

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;
do php /var/www/html/project/path/to/vend_$i.php;
done;
```

and in the crontab just write :

```
0 */8 * * * root /path/to/phpcron.sh
```

thats it.

Comment: What is the crontab? Can you please give me more details.

Comment: for `cronjob`, you must edit `/etc/crontab` file , and write the line to the end of it, and then, run `service crond restart`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a cron job set to execute `/wp-content/themes/mythemename/cron.php` every 8 hours, then you can do this:

Copy the following code into `cron.php`:

```
<?php

// Execute The vend_X.php scripts
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    include("/wp-content/themes/mythemename/vend_". $i .".php");
}

?>
```

The act of including those vend_x.php file will execute the scripts.

Comment: At this moment my cron.php is empty